# How can i add contacts in delivery options field for voting button in outlook using powershell?

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server

I want to select 'have replies sent to' checkbox and add certain list of people to send them voting button response. How to do this using powershell script?

Comment: What have you tried? what have you searched for? Show us your code? Show us your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are interested in the [ReplyRecipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.replyrecipients?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1355)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) property which returns a [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients) collection that represents all the reply recipient objects for the Outlook item.